Workarounds for Safari z-indices, while keeping different transformed heights?
I work with a pure CSS parallax scroll effect, based on the perspective property. To achieve the parallax effect, an element (in codepen the image-class) is translated with positive z values. This makes it seem like the element is scrolled faster than the rest of the document - the desired effect. In Safari however, this translation causes the element to be displayed in front of other slower-scrolled content. The z-index property just gets ignored. This behavior differs from Firefox, Chrome, and Edge, where the content stays in front of the parallax element at all times (as it should).
I reproduced the problem in codepen.
Is there a way to force Safari to display the actual content in front of the parallax content, without breaking the parallax effect?
My Observations:
I tried to give the content a higher / equal z-translation. This leads to the content being displayed above the parallax element (which is great) but also scrolled at the same speed (no parallax effect -> bad). In my testing,  I could only sacrifice either the correct placement of content or the parallax effect. Do I miss something, or is it just impossible with pure CSS.
I could make it work by adding a couple of lines of JS into the scroll-EventListener, but this would be worse for performance than the CSS solution.
